# Can I have Full Screen ViewController presented, but still able to swipe down, to get back to Parent (launcher) ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

In iOS 13, when we present a new ViewController

```
         let newVC = NewViewController()
         self.present(newVC, animated: true)
```

it looks like below, where it is not FullScreen, and can be swipe down to move back to the launching ViewController

[image]

To make it FullScreen, we can just use `.fullScreen` as shown below.

```
         let newVC = NewViewController()
         newVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
         self.present(newVC, animated: true)
```

It will look like below, which is full screen. However, it doesn't allow me to swipe down to get back to the parent anymore.

[image]

Is there a way to swipe back and get back to Parent still with FullScreen on?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803695/is-it-possible-to-use-swipe-to-dismiss-while-presenting-a-fullscreen-modal-in-io

Comment: You would need to write a custom interactive transition animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    //Button is added via storyboard
    @IBAction func presentButtonDidTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vc = NewViewController()
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}

class NewViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .gray
        
        let gesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissVC))
        gesture.direction = .down
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true // For UIImageView
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
    
    @objc
    private func dismissVC() {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's. It doesn't work when the UIViewController has an UIImageView. Why is that so?

Comment: Need to add `view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` when It is `UIImageView`