# Can UISwipeGestureRecognizer work for view in UIHostingController?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiswipegesturerecognizer, uihostingcontroller

As per answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64726641/3286489, I can perform a swipe down to dismiss a fullscreen ViewController using `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`.

However, when I transfer the same code to `UIHostingController` as below, it doesn't work anymore

```
class ContextViewController: UIHostingController<CustomDrawViewWrapper> {

    let drawViewWrapper: CustomDrawViewWrapper
    
    init(drawView: CustomDrawView) {
        self.drawViewWrapper = CustomDrawViewWrapper(drawView: drawView)
        super.init(rootView: self.drawViewWrapper)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let gesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissVC))
        gesture.direction = .down
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
        
    @objc
    private func dismissVC() {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Anything I need to do to get the swipe down working for `UIHostingController`?

Note: the swipe down to dismiss still work if the `UIHostingController` is not in fullscreen mode.

Comment: Having the same problem with an edge pan gesture. Doesn't even register on it's containing UIView